# TestNG Groovy dependsOnMethods

Tags: groovy, annotations, testng

Is there any way to use *dependsOnMethods* in my TestNG annotation's for tests written in groovy as so?

```
class WarehouseBehavior {
    @Test
    void shouldHaveWarehouse() {
        def warehouse = registry.getService Warehouse.class
        assertNotNull warehouse
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = ['shouldHaveWarehouse'])
    void shouldStoreDataInWarehouse() {
        def warehouse = registry.getService Warehouse.class
        warehouse.store(['a': 'b', 'c': 'd'])
    }
}
```

I'm either missing something here or groovy just doesn't support this type of annotations since similar code works perfectly well in Java while running this in groovy gives me the following error

```
WarehouseBehavior.shouldStoreDataInWarehouse() is depending on method public void WarehouseBehavior.shouldHaveWarehouse(), which is not annotated with @Test
```

Answer (score 0):

`Test` method has package scope.

Explicitly declare `public` as:

```
@Test
public void shouldHaveWarehouse() {
    // .....
}
```

Comment: It would make a lot of sense if this was Java, but it's not since as stated in [Differences from Java](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java) Groovy makes methods and classes public by default.
In other words `void shouldHaveWarehouse() { /* ... */ }` is exactly the same as `public void shouldHaveWarehouse() { /* ... */ }` only a little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This is not (complete) answer IMO, but it's more of workaround. Just adding it here in case somebody can improve this answer and provide more insights.

Facing the same issue with Groovy tests and only workaround I can find till now is to have both the methods in same group and then it works. So something like this

```
class WarehouseBehavior {
    @Test(groups =['somegroup'])
    void shouldHaveWarehouse() {
        def warehouse = registry.getService Warehouse.class
        assertNotNull warehouse
    }
    @Test(groups =['somegroup'], dependsOnMethods = ['shouldHaveWarehouse'])
    void shouldStoreDataInWarehouse() {
        def warehouse = registry.getService Warehouse.class
        warehouse.store(['a': 'b', 'c': 'd'])
    }
}
```